# Get an EXACT value in $_POST array

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I'm studying php and I'm trying to figure out how to get the string `"Juve_Milan"` from this `var_dump($_POST)` :

```
    array(5) {
    ["Juve_Milan"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "5" [1] => string(1)
        "1"
    }["Inter_Roma"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "4" [1] => string(1)
        "4"
    }["Napoli_Lazio"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "2" [1] => string(1)
        "5"
    }["name"] => string(0)
    "" ["submit"] => string(5)
    "Invia"
}
```

I could get all of them with:

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$param_name."</td><td>".$param_val[0]."-".$param_val[1]."</td></tr>";
}
```

But i want to get them exactly **one by one**, for example, if i want to get the string "Juve_Milan" or "inter_Roma" how can i do? 
Without looping, how can i get the string value: "Juve_milan" or "Inter_Roma"? Becouse with the loop i can access them this way : `$_POST as $param_name => $param_val`
But i want to get them without loop, my first attempt was something like `$_POST[0][0]` but its wrong...

Comment: what do you want? The array data for key specified?

Comment: What do you mean one by one? `var_dump($_POST['Juve_Milan']);` will give you the value. If you're not looping the array by `key=>value` then you'll need to know the key. `array_keys($_POST)` will give you the keys as an array but I doubt that's useful

Comment: Sorry i update my question becouse it's not clear.

Comment: Where are you getting the array? is it from a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numbers of php array functions you can use. 
You can use

> array shift

to remove an element from an array and display it .e.g

```
$club = ['juve_millan', 'inter_roma', 'napoli_lazio'];
$juve = array_shift($club);

echo $juve;// 'juve_millan'
```

but note that the array is shortened by one element i.e. 'juve_millan' is no more in the array and also note that using

> array_shift

over larger array is fairly slow

> Array Slice function

PHP

> array_slice()

function is used to extract a slice of an array e.g

```
$club = ['juve_millan', 'inter_roma', 'napoli_lazio'];
```

if I want to display

> inter_roma

or assigned it to a variable, then I can do this

```
$roma = array_slice($club, 1, 1);// The first parameter is the array to slice, the second parameter is where to begin(which is one since most programming language array index start from 0 meaning juve_millan is zero, while inter_roma is 1, napoli_lazio is 2) and the length is 1 since i want to return a single element.
```

I hope you understand

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate over keys of the main array like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$param_name."</td></tr>";
}
```

This will return each `Juve_Milan`, `Inter_Roma` etc. one by one. Although it's part of the code you already have, I believe this will return values you want only.